# Perl regex to output lines not containing a character

Tags: regex, perl

Basically there are two types of lines (simplified):

"John" (2002)

Amy    (1991)

There may or may not be tabs at the beginning. I want to only get the lines not containing double quotes. So far I have

```
if( /([^\t]*) [\t]+ ^("(.*?)") ([^\t]+ [\ ]* [\(][\d]+[\)])/)
```

If i take out the carat sign, it'll grab the lines with the double quotes. I want it to do the opposite but it's not working.

Comment: Does it need to be Perl? ``sed '/"/d' inputfile.txt``

Answer (score 3):

I'd try this (or do I simplify too much?):

```
jj@ubuntu:~$ cat /tmp/x.txt 
"John" (2002)
Amy (1991)
rc@ubuntu:~$ perl -ne 'print unless /"/' < /tmp/x.txt 
Amy (1991)
```

Comment: You could simplify (or golf) that, to `perl -ne'/"/||print' x.txt`

Comment: One fewer character `grep -v \" x.txt`

Comment: Standing toothpicks (or a broken comb?):  `perl -ne'y|"||||print' x.txt`

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^"]*$
```

With the modifier that let ^$ match at line breaks

I originally suggested lookaround but its not needed here

```
^((?!").)*$)
```

Comment: It uses a technique called positive lookahead which you can read upon here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html In Perl to get an array of all regex matches in a string use @result = $subject =~ m/^(?!").*$/mg;

Comment: if( /([^\t]*) [\t]+ ^(?!").*$ ([^\t]+ [\ ]* [\(][\d]+[\)])/)

like that?? It doesn't work

Comment: @user1224478 Nope, it's just the simple regex ^(?!").*$ that will only match lines not containing a double quote "

Comment: Your regex will actually match any line that doesn't *start* with a double-quote. For example, it would match `"\t\"John\" (2002)"`.

Comment: @ruakh Good catch. The regex is improved.

Comment: Yeah but, its better to use `^[^"]*$` for a single char, while using `^(?:(?!<sentence>).)*$` for words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
if (/^\s*([^"\s]+)\s*\((\d+)\)\s*$/) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know that

```
if (/regex/) { ... }
```

does the opposite of what you want to do, don't try to figure out what the "opposite" of `/regex/` is. It's much more understandable to use the opposite of `if`:

```
unless (/regex/) { ... }
if ( !/regex/ ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `!/"/` as an equivalent of `/^[^"]*$/`